# React hooks with multiple state values not working but separate state value works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, use-state

I am changing my code with hooks with only basic knowledge. The example format below which is a separate state value with a conditional statement works with my input form but:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState(null);


const onChangeHandler = event => {
   const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;

   if (name === "userEmail") {setEmail(value)}
   else if (name === "userPassword") {setPassword(value)}
   else if (name === "userName") {setUserName(value)}
};
```

when I try to put it inside a single state like the example below it does not work and goes directly to the error message:

```
const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
  userName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  error: null,
});


const { userName, email, password, error } = newUser

const onChangeHandler = event => {
  const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;

  setNewUser({...newUser, [name]: value})
};
```

with the input field, that works on the separate state value, but doesn't work with the multiple state value and field is not clickable:

```
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Control
        size="lg"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        name="userName"
        value={userName}
        onChange={event => onChangeHandler(event)}
        required
      />
    </Form.Group>
    
    <Form.Group> 
      <Form.Control
        size="lg"
        type="email"
        name="userEmail"
        placeholder="E-mail"
        value={email}
        onChange={event => onChangeHandler(event)}
        required
      />
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Control
        type={"password"}
        placeholder="Password"
        name="userPassword"
        value={password}
        onChange={event => onChangeHandler(event)}
        required
      />
    </Form.Group>
```

Comment: is it working for the `Username` input ?

Comment: yes i the only thing that is editable is the username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up names.
In the initial state you have following:

```
const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
  userName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  error: null,
});
```

But while changing the values, you set the values to be `userName` , `userEmail`, `userPassword`. As mentioned in the JSX below, you added the `name` prop of each field.

***Get the names synchronized and you are good to go!***

Comment: so that's the only thing I need to change. Thank you so much. Hooks is such a nosebleed

Comment: Haha, hooks are easy, it's just a different perspective. as the hooks creator Dan Abramov said. "you have to think the hooks way". Also, do up-vote if this answer helped, so it can help others as well!

Comment: I did upvote but I have less than 15 reputaions yet. I just got used to class component so much.